# SQL Batch Import/Insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a sitution where I need to import records from a flat file into several tables, making sure to keep tab on the resulting Primary keys for each row insert, for insertion into the next table.

Example

```
For each Row in FlatFile_Import 

    RowID = INSERT Row_ELEMENTS1 INTO TABLEA

    PROPID = INSERT ROW_ELEMENTS2 & ROWID INTO TABLEB

    ATTRID = INSERT ROW_ELEMENTS3 & PROPID INTO TABLEC

    . . .  ..
NEXt
```

I have a staging table, **StagingTable** filled with data from an excel file. Each row of the data in **StagingTable** contains records that need to be inserted into various tables(TableA, TableB, and TableC). Now when I insert the columns from each row that go to **TableA**, I need to retrieve the created/generated primarykey,  **KeyA** Next I select to insert the columns from **StagingTable** row that should go into **TableB**, along with **KeyA**, and get back **KeyB** and so on and so forth.

How can I best handle this requirement please?

Comment: And your question is what, exactly?? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Where are you stuck when doing your flat file import? What DBMS are you using? We'd like to help you with your problem, but we don't write your code for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes you can Modify the TableA and TableB to add a column.

Load the Data into StagingTable .Staging table should have  StageRecordID ( identity).
Then you need to modify the TableA to add a colum StageRecordID. Store the StageRecordId in this column  when populating TABLEA.
WHEN populating TableB join the StagingTable with TableA to get RowID of TableA
similarly Store StageRecordID in TableB aswell so that you can join to it When Populating TABLEC

**Edit**:some example code

```
--Assuming TableA is 

/*
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
{
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,Row_ELEMENTS1 varchar(25)
,StageRecordID int  ---you need to add this column to the Table
}
*/
INSERT INTO TABLEA
(
Row_ELEMENTS1,
StageRecordID
)
   SELECT Col1 AS Row_ELEMENTS1,StageRecordID FROM StaginTable


--NOW assuming TABLEB is 

/*
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
{
PROPID  INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,Row_ELEMENTS2 varchar(25)
,ROWID 
,StageRecordID int ---you need to add this column to the Table
}
*/
INSERT INTO TABLEB
(
Row_ELEMENTS2,
ROWID,
StageRecordID
   )
    SELECT a.Col2 AS Row_ELEMENTS2, b.ROWID ,a.StageRecordID FROM StaginTable AS a
    INNER JOIN TABLEA AS b
    ON a.StageRecordID=b.StageRecordID
```

Comment: I have the data in a staging table, but I am not sure how to handle the batch processing in this case. I currently have about 30,000 records to import into my tables. An INSERT INTO . . . SELECT FROM  . . . STATEMENT would probably insert into TABLEA but I don't think it ensures that I am able to return the Primarykeys in Order for the  insert into the next table. Can you please expound on your suggestion there please?

Comment: @Kobojunkie perhaps you can expand on your question?

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. I will need to update my Tables to include the staging ID, rowID's necessary.